# Querying a JSONB in .NET Core and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am trying to make a query on a JSONB field, which perfectly works in the pgAdmin, but when i paste the query into my C# .NET Core Code it throws an exception:

System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.

This is my C# Code:

```
var query = Request.Form["query"].ToString();
var result = _context.Competitions.FromSql(query).ToList();
```

The value of the query variable is the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM public."Competitions" WHERE public."Competitions"."Data" @> '[{"last_name": "Aked"}]';
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Important info:
When i pass a regular SQL Query like e.g. "Select * from Competitions" the whole thing works perfectly.

Comment: I am wondering if the " will need to be escaped \" since it is cast to a string? Have you tried that?

Comment: I think that must have been the problem, but meanwhile i forgot the solution. I'll try to update the question with the solution. Thanks @ChristopherJ.Reynolds